# Why Frme windowClosing with ConfirmDialog closes with both cases(OK & Cancel)?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, windowlistener

here is my code :

```
            addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
               int a = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, 
                            "Are you sure you want to exit the program?", "Exit Program ",
                            JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
               System.out.println(a);
               if(a==JOptionPane.OK_OPTION){
                   dispose();
               }
           }});
```

The problem is either `a==OK_OPTION` or `a==CANCEL_OPTION` the frame will close.

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have set the default close operation of `JFrame` as `EXIT_ON_CLOSE`. So this exits the `JFrame` no matter if you press `OK` or `CANCEL`. You should instead set the default close operation as `DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE` if you want to manually handle the close operation of your `JFrame`.

```
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
               int a = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, 
                            "Are you sure you want to exit the program?", "Exit Program ",
                            JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
               System.out.println(a);
               if(a==JOptionPane.OK_OPTION){
                   dispose();//You can use System.exit(0) if you want to exit the JVM
               }
           }});
```